# include problems with <?xml | readfile problems with image relative paths

Tags: php, xml, include, readfile

I have two files with the paths:

```
/reader.php
/ebook/titlepage.xhtml
```

I plan for the reader to eventually read the ebooks toc.ncx and be able to display this in a left hand pane for easy navigation. However for now, all I want to do is get around my problem with displaying the xhtml file.

The ebook titlepage starts like:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
```

The problem is when I use

```
include(/ebook/titlepage.xhtml);
```

I get unexpected version T_String because my server is set up to use the short open tag

I tried to use `ini_set('short_open_tag', '0')` before my include to no avail
Then I tried `readfile('ebook/titlepage.xhtml')` which works except the images are referenced relative from reader.php rather than relevant from the titlepage.xhtml.

I do not want to edit any of the ebooks files so using `echo <?xml...` is out the question; I eventually wish to have all the file packaged in ebook.epub and to try and use php to navigate the archive to read and display the files in my reader

I suppose my question is, how can I get read file to use paths relative to ebook without editing any of the ebbok files? or how can I use include and ignore

Or, perhaps there is a better way that I am unaware of here. Perhaps a way to load the html file and process only the stuff within  or just the body, or the head and body since I would like to make use of the styles and titles in head eventually.

**Update (Solved) using pasfree's answer**

I now load the HTML into a domdocument and add a base tag to the head before outputting it using savehtml

```
            //Load the ebook title page
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->loadHTMLFile("{$_GET["book"]}/titlepage.xhtml");

            //Create the base element
            $base = $doc->createElement("base");
            $baseHref = $doc->createAttribute('href');
            $baseHref->value = "{$_GET["book"]}/";
            $base->appendChild($baseHref);

            //add <base...> to <head>
            $head = $doc->getElementsByTagName("head")->item(0);
            $head->appendChild($base);

            //output the page
            echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Thanks

Comment: This is why we don't use code features for documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

readfile() is right for inserting the files content.
You can use file_get_contents() too.

A good practice, is to set a global base href in your html docs so the relative paths will be resolved correctly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/base

Comment: Hi, I have placed: <base href="ebook/"></base> into my titlepage.xhtml <head> tags and it seems to have done the trick...

I have avoided using reference to http://... etc because I don't know how that will affect an ereader when the pages are opened.

I'll accept this as the answer when I can confirm base will not affect the ereaders capabilities to use the epub :)

Comment: Ok, So I didn't fancy editing the epub pages but instead found out how to load the HTML file and edit it before rendering it in my page. I have posted this above. I think being able to edit the HTML before rendering it could proove useful later. Thanks again